# The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed. - How to add more root Elements?

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm trying to add second Element in root called posiadajacy_samochod. I don't know how I'm supposed to do it. I need to declare two namespaces. Is this something about closing the brackets? I need solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE dane_osobowe [
<!ELEMENT dane_osobowe (imie,nazwisko,adres,kod_pocztowy,miejscowosc,pesel,wiek,nr_telefonu,znak_zodiaku)>
<!ELEMENT imie (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT nazwisko (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT adres (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT kod_pocztowy (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT miejscowosc (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT pesel (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT nr_telefonu (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT wiek (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT znak_zodiaku (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT posiadany_samochod (marka,model,rok_produkcji,pojemnosc,ilosc_km,przebieg)>
<!ELEMENT marka (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT model (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT rok_produkcji (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT pojemnosc (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ilosc_km (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT przebieg (#PCDATA)>
]>



<dane_osobowe>
<imie>Jan</imie>
<nazwisko>Kowalski</nazwisko>
<adres>ul. Jasna 17A</adres>
<kod_pocztowy>81-031</kod_pocztowy>
<miejscowosc>Katowice</miejscowosc>
<pesel>92035213213</pesel>
<wiek>27</wiek>
<nr_telefonu>742132513</nr_telefonu>
<znak_zodiaku>byk</znak_zodiaku>
</dane_osobowe>

<posiadany_samochod>
<marka>BWM</marka>
<model>X6</model>
<rok_produkcji>2015</rok_produkcji>
<pojemnosc>3.0</pojemnosc>
<ilosc_km>313</ilosc_km>
<przebieg>63000</przebieg>
</posiadany_samochod>
```

Answer (score 0):

An xml file is basically a tree. There can only be one root.
So your two nodes need to be children of the one true root.
Children are identified by keeping an extra tab space from their parent's indentation.

This is what you want to do:

```
<root>
    <dane_osobowe>
    <imie>Jan</imie>
    <nazwisko>Kowalski</nazwisko>
    <adres>ul. Jasna 17A</adres>
    <kod_pocztowy>81-031</kod_pocztowy>
    <miejscowosc>Katowice</miejscowosc>
    <pesel>92035213213</pesel>
    <wiek>27</wiek>
    <nr_telefonu>742132513</nr_telefonu>
    <znak_zodiaku>byk</znak_zodiaku>
    </dane_osobowe>

    <posiadany_samochod>
    <marka>BWM</marka>
    <model>X6</model>
    <rok_produkcji>2015</rok_produkcji>
    <pojemnosc>3.0</pojemnosc>
    <ilosc_km>313</ilosc_km>
    <przebieg>63000</przebieg>
    </posiadany_samochod>
</root>
```